# LINQ to XML: don't get XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

it should be easy but I don't really see my fault.

```
public static void Edit(string old, string neew, string type)
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Xml.xml");

        switch (type)
        {
            case "Customer":

                XElement name = root.Descendants("Data").Descendants("Customer")
                    .Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value.ToString() == old)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                name.SetElementValue("Name", neew);
                break;
```

XElement name returns null, so I get a NullReferenceException. But I don't know, why it only returns null.

This is my Xml structure:

```
<Data>   
            <Customer>
                <Name>CustomerA</Name>
                <IP>888.888.888.888</IP>
                <UserLogin>auser</UserLogin>
                <UserPw>apwd</UserPw>   
            </Customer>   
            <Customer>
                <Name>CustomerB</Name>
                <IP>102.16.70.181</IP>
                <UserLogin>buser</UserLogin>
                <UserPw>bpwd</UserPw>   
            </Customer> 
        </Data>
```

Maybe someone could open my eyes and help me? Or give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems `Data` is already your root element. You can use  `root.Elements("Customer")` or `root.Descendants("Customer")` instead.

Apart from that `XElement.Value` property is of type `string`, so you don't need to call `ToString` on it.Also you may consider using explicit casts like `(string)x.Element("Name") == old` to avoid exceptions if the elements isn't found.

Comment: Hi, thanks, you're right with the root element. I was so confused and searched at the linq part because I'm new with it! Thanks also for the advice with the XElement.Value. Well, I wasn't sure but, yeah, if I hover it, it tands right there that's a string. Good evening!